# Save multiple people/groups in a People or Group field using SP 2013 REST API

Tags: 2013, rest, splistitem, ajax, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to save a list item in SP 2013 using REST API.

One of the fields, named `AccessRights`, is a People or Groups type field.

My code works fine when I use this:

```
dataToSave["AccessRightsId"] = 46;
//add other fields
//post through REST API
```

However, I need to save **multiple** groups or people in this field.

Following [this blog post](http://sharepoint.sureshc.com/2016/05/how-to-update-person-field-with-multiple-values-using-rest-api.html), I am trying to send the request like this:

[image]

Instead of just group ID, I am trying to use an object that consists of the `"results"` property that has an array of group IDs.

This fails with the following error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
>
> "message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.

I've tried to use both `string` and `number` values in the array ("47" and 47), neither work.

What's the correct way to save multiple people or groups via REST API into a People or Group field?

Comment: From the error it looks like your field is not a multi-field. Can you verify that your user field is multivalued?

Comment: @Kai you were right!

Comment: Ok, I will add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that `PrimitiveValue` expected.

That means SharePoint assumes your actual field type is single-value, you need to switch it to multiple selection.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was because the "Allow multiple selections" option in the column settings was off. Need to change it to "Yes":

[image]